# psd Image creation with layer properties using CGImageRef

Tags: cocoa, macos, cgimage, psd

Working in Mac OSX, Cocoa

I have an psd image with layered property.
I want to crop it to the crop rect and save this cropped image with the settings of original image.

I am using CGImageRef for all the image related operations.

I have enclosed the code i used to crop the image is given below. But it fails to create the layered image.

```
NSImage *img = [[NSImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithData:[img TIFFRepresentation]];
CGImageRef imageRef = [rep CGImage];
CGImageRef cropedImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(imageRef, cropRect);


CGImageDestinationRef idst = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL( url, type, 1, NULL );
if( idst != NULL ) {

           CGImageDestinationAddImage( idst, image, properties );
           bool success = CGImageDestinationFinalize( idst );

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to read separate layers from PSD files in Mac OS X with only built-in APIs. Everything is almost certainly going to go through CGImageSource, and CGImageSource does not support reading separate layers from PSD files. ([The documentation says this explicitly for the `CGImageSourceGetCount` function](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageSource/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageSourceGetCount), and experimentation using only `CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex` bears it out.)

You'll need to use a third-party PSD-reading library.

Comment: Is there any library for Read and Write .psd images? 
And it also has to support crop!.

Comment: Dhanaraj: You should ask that as a separate question.

Comment: You can do it with Carbon/Quicktime.