# Open source for reading and writing multi layer .psd image

Tags: cocoa, macos, cgimage, psd

I am in Mac OSX, Cocoa .

I want to read and write multi layered .psd images. 
With Cocoa native api's i can read or write the images as flat images.(i.e., single layered)

So is there any 3rd party library available to perform the operations?

This is my earlier query.
[psd Image creation with layer properties using CGImageRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456560/psd-image-creation-with-layer-properties-using-cgimageref)

Thanks,
Dhana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PSD is a lousy format for anything but use in PhotoShop, and most third party libraries will miss some of the finer points of layer composition, in part because Adobe keeps extending the format, and in part because it isn't extremely well documented.

If you need to keep altered images in PSD, then presumably you have PhotoShop in-house. Your best bet is to use [Photoshop Batch Processing](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7452a.html) which can be as easy as keyboard macros or as complex as you want [to script](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7419a.html).

Comment: I think it is not publicly documented at all.

Comment: Except it's a parser and not a writer.